# Gradle - difference between ext {...} and ext['...'] in the buildScript section

Tags: gradle

So for example

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        kotlinVersion = „1.3.50”
    }

    ext['tomcat.version'] = '9.0.56’
}
```

What exactly is the difference between those two? Cannot find it in the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Its groovy access syntax `map["age"] = 42` ; dot operator `way map.city = "New York"`

also explained in the docs
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtraPropertiesExtension.html